# Cannot run the query as it says "unable to execute query, invalid operation or syntax using multi-valued field" in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, syntax

```
SELECT
    tbl_facilityinformation.exportid,
    qry_numberofpatientsgreaterthan12withdepressionscreen.numberofuniquepatientsagegreaterthan12withdepressionscreening AS NumberUniquePatientsWithDepressionScreening,
    qry_numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years.numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years,
    [qry_numberofpatientsgreaterthan12withdepressionscreen]![numberofuniquepatientsagegreaterthan12withdepressionscreening] /
    [qry_numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years]![numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years] AS PercentageOfPatientsGreaterThan12WithDepressionScreen
FROM   
    (
        tbl_facilityinformation INNER JOIN qry_numberofpatientsgreaterthan12withdepressionscreen ON 
        tbl_facilityinformation.exportid = qry_numberofpatientsgreaterthan12withdepressionscreen.exportid
    )
    INNER JOIN qry_numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years ON 
    tbl_facilityinformation.exportid = qry_numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years.exportid
GROUP BY 
    tbl_facilityinformation.exportid,
    qry_numberofpatientsgreaterthan12withdepressionscreen.numberofuniquepatientsagegreaterthan12withdepressionscreening,
    qry_numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years.numberofuniquepersonsgreaterthan12years;
```

I dont understand why I'm getting the error:

> Unable to execute query, invalid operation or syntax using multi-valued field.

I have tried to look for syntax errors but could not find any.

Comment: if you replace  select ... from... by section by select 1 from.., the problem occurs also ? Just to check if the select is the culprit

Comment: You'll need to either include the percentage calculation within the `group by` clause, or apply an aggregate function such as `sum` to the calculation (or remove the `group by` clause altogether).